# Google Closure Compiler @param annotation for variable parameters

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I have a function that can accept a variable number of parameters.

According to [Google Closure Compiler wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#variable-parameters-in-param-annotations), this is the way to do it using `@param` annotation.

```
/**
 * Takes 2 or more strings and do something cool with them.
 * @param {...string} var_args
 * @return {string} the processed result
 */
function doSomethingCool() {
    var len = arguments.length;
    if (len < 2) {
        throw Error('Need at least 2 arguments');
    }

    ...
}
```

### Problem

When I try compiling it, I see this warning: `JSC_INEXISTENT_PARAM: parameter var_args does not appear in doSomethingCool's parameter list at line 6 character 1`

So I tried `@param {string} arguments`, but same error.

I also tried `@param {string}` with no variable name. I got: `JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation. expecting a variable name in a @param tag.`

#### Question

What did I do wrong and how can variable parameters be annotated for Closure Compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var_args` needs to actually appear in the parameter list which is what the error is telling you.

```
/**
 * Takes 2 or more strings and do something cool with them.
 * @param {...string} var_args
 * @return {string} the processed result
 */
function doSomethingCool(var_args) {}
```

Closure-compiler will recognize that it's never referenced and remove it during compilation.

If having it listed there bothers you, you can use an `@type` annotation instead:

```
/**
 * Takes 2 or more strings and do something cool with them.
 * @type {function(...string):string}
 */
function doSomethingCool() {}
```

If you really want correct type checking, annotate the function so that it takes 2 or more strings:

```
/**
 * Takes 2 or more strings and do something cool with them.
 * @type {function(string, string, ...string):string}
 */
function doSomethingCool() {}
```

Comment: I was actually hoping to stick to `@param` annotation for consistency across all functions. Looks like I have no choice but to use `@type` annotation for these functions.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could just write your code more efficiently. Using the `arguments` object is generally considered bad practice because it adds extra overhead to that function and prevents certain JIST optimizations. If you need to pass a variable number of things to `doSomethingCool`, then just pass `doSomethingCool` a variable-length array as the first argument.